# Creating a Google Map in Laravel,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-maps-api-3

I try to display Google Map which is display an address from database(I have address column in DB table). For this I made a blade, and bind to route and path it with controller. I am having display issue.

My step is right below. I used this google API.

```
https://github.com/farhanwazir/laravelgooglemaps
```

And set the route:

```
Route::get('/show', 'PagesController@map');
```

Set the controller:

```
public function map(){

    $config['center'] = allestates::where('address')->get();
    $config['zoom'] = '10';
    $config['map_width'] = '300px';
    $config['scrollwheel'] = false;

    GMaps::initialize($config);

    $map = GMaps::create_map();

    return view('pages.show',[ 'map' => $map]);
}
```

And in my blade. This is how I am calling it in body tag.

```
{{$map['html']}}
```

But getting this error.

> Non-static method FarhanWazir\GoogleMaps\GMaps::initialize() should
>   not be called statically

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: do it like this `return view(pages.show)->with(['map'=> $map]);` and then test what is returning from `$map` to use as a value in your blade template

Comment: please, first check value is set in the variable or not using isset.

Comment: Also use this :    return view('pages.show', ['map' => $map]);

Comment: @RajenderVerma I tried that but still giving undefined var error

Comment: @TrickStar tried that but still having undefined $map error. And value is not empty in DB table. I have address there.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
$gmap = new GMaps();
$gmap->initialize($config);

$map = $gmap->create_map();
return view('your_view', compact('map'));
```

Notice that `$gmap->create_map()` is not a static calling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this

```
return view('pages.show',[ 'map' => $map]);
return view(pages.show)->with(['map'=> $map]);
```

Also check if the value is not empty

Goodluck

Comment: thank you for your answer but still having $map undefined error. And value is not empty in DB table. I have address there.

Comment: Well then we need to declare the problem. I think that your variable is not set in your function so check it with : {{ isset($map) ? $map : '' }}. also make a test function with a string variable and check your view, see if you have the same issue.

Comment: okay the error is changed. mate `Non-static method FarhanWazir\GoogleMaps\GMaps::initialize() should not be called statically` this is what I amn getting now.

Comment: ok, try to make a dynamic call. for laravel you can put : use GMaps insted of use FarhanWazir\GoogleMaps\GMaps. or make a construct test controller.